# Issues with unflattened SVG

Tags: svg

I have an issue with some SVG markup - I have tried every export setting in Adobe Illustrator and yet I can't seem to get a flattened SVG.

You seem to be able to adjust every letter in this - I want it flattened so it appears as just one block

I have tried adjusting all of the Illustrator settings and even converting the SVG file online

I want the SVG to be lightweight and one block rather than split into each letter

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbdrzE)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="780px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 780 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 780 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#EDC0F9;}
    .st1{fill:#333333;}
    .st2{fill:#D892EC;}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path class="st0" d="M35.2,17.3c7.2,0,15.2,1,21.8,6.9c7.1,6.3,8.1,14.4,8.1,20.2c0,10.4-3.9,16.3-7.1,19.5
                    c-6.6,6.8-15.3,7.4-21.1,7.4H25v29.1H5.8V17.3H35.2z M25,55.5h6.9c2.6,0,7.2-0.1,10.3-3.1c1.7-1.7,3.1-4.6,3.1-8.2
                    c0-3.4-1.2-6.4-3.1-8.1c-2.8-2.7-7-3.1-10.7-3.1H25V55.5z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M116.2,17.3c10.6,0,17.2,3.4,21.1,7.2c3.4,3.3,7.2,9.3,7.2,18.5c0,5.3-1.1,11.7-6.5,16.9
                    c-2.8,2.7-7,5.3-11.6,6.4l25.5,33.9h-23.4l-22.1-32.6v32.7H87.1v-83H116.2z M106.3,55h4.3c3.4,0,8.2-0.4,11.4-3.6
                    c1.4-1.4,3.1-3.9,3.1-8.1c0-4.7-2.2-7.2-3.8-8.5c-3.1-2.3-8.1-2.6-10.6-2.6h-4.4V55z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M219.6,33.5H192v16.1h26.4v16.2H192v18.4h27.8v16.2h-47v-83h46.9V33.5z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M271.2,84.1h35.6v16.2h-67.1l39.8-66.7h-33.3V17.4h64.7L271.2,84.1z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M358.5,84.1H394v16.2H327l39.8-66.8h-33.3V17.3h64.7L358.5,84.1z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M445.2,61.6l-29.7-44.3h22.6l16.7,25.8l16.7-25.8h22.6l-29.7,44.3v38.7h-19.2V61.6z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M539.4,17.3c4.4,0,14.7,0.2,21.1,6.4c5.4,5.1,6,12,6,15.7c0,3.2-0.5,7-2.7,10.6c-2.1,3.4-5,5.3-7,6.1
                    c3.9,0.6,8.5,2.6,11.4,5.6c2.7,2.7,5.4,7.5,5.4,14.9c0,8.4-3.2,13.5-6.5,16.8c-6.9,6.6-16.8,7.1-21.9,7.1H514v-83H539.4z
                     M533,50.9h3.1c2.6,0,7-0.4,9.7-2.3c1.7-1.2,3.3-3.7,3.3-7.4s-1.7-5.9-3.2-7c-2.7-2.1-6.5-2.1-10-2.1h-3v18.8H533z M533,85.3
                    h4.6c4.8,0,10.7-0.1,14.1-3.3c1.7-1.6,2.7-3.9,2.7-7c0-3.3-1.4-5.6-2.6-6.7c-3.3-3.1-9.8-3.1-13.6-3.1H533V85.3z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M671,27.5c7.9,7.6,12.9,18.5,12.9,31.3c0,11.1-3.9,22.4-12.9,31.1c-7.7,7.5-18.2,12.2-32.1,12.2
                    c-15.6,0-26.2-6.3-32.3-12.2c-8-7.5-12.9-18.7-12.9-30.8c0-11.9,5.4-24,12.8-31.5c5.6-5.6,16-12.2,32.4-12.2
                    C651.8,15.4,662.6,19.4,671,27.5z M620.6,40.1c-3.6,3.4-7.4,9.6-7.4,18.8c0,7.6,2.5,13.6,7.6,18.7c5.4,5.1,11.3,6.9,17.8,6.9
                    c8.5,0,14.4-3.1,18.4-7.1c3.2-3.1,7.2-9,7.2-18.5c0-8.6-3.4-15-7.2-18.7c-4.1-3.9-10.7-7.1-18.3-7.1
                    C631.5,33.1,625,35.7,620.6,40.1z"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M726.7,56.2l-25.8-38.9h23l13.6,23.6l13.6-23.6h23l-25.8,38.9l30.5,44.1h-23l-18.4-28.7l-18.4,28.7h-23
                    L726.7,56.2z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M21,96.4H1V12.5h29.7c6.7,0,15.2,0.8,22,7c5.6,4.8,8.2,11.5,8.2,20.5c0,8.2-2.4,14.9-7.2,19.8
                    c-6.5,6.7-14.9,7.5-21.4,7.5H21V96.4z M1.8,95.5h18.4V66.4h12.1c6.4,0,14.5-0.8,20.8-7.2c4.6-4.8,7-11.3,7-19.2
                    c0-8.7-2.6-15.2-8-19.8c-6.7-6-15-6.9-21.4-6.9H1.8V95.5z M27.5,51.7h-7.3V28.2h6.9c3.7,0,8,0.4,11,3.2c2,1.9,3.2,5,3.2,8.4
                    c0,3.3-1.2,6.5-3.2,8.5C34.6,51.7,29.6,51.7,27.5,51.7z M21,50.7h6.4c2,0,6.9,0,10-3c1.9-1.9,2.9-4.7,2.9-7.9s-1.1-6-2.9-7.8
                    c-2.7-2.6-6.8-3-10.4-3h-6.1L21,50.7L21,50.7z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M148.4,96.4H124l-21.7-31.7v31.7H82.1V12.5h29.5c11.2,0,17.9,3.9,21.4,7.4c2.7,2.6,7.4,8.6,7.4,18.9
                    c0,7.3-2.1,12.9-6.6,17.3c-3,2.9-7.1,5.2-11.1,6.3L148.4,96.4z M124.4,95.5h22.3l-25.4-33.8l0.6-0.2c4.1-1,8.3-3.2,11.4-6.3
                    c4.2-4.1,6.4-9.6,6.4-16.6c0-9.9-4.4-15.7-7.1-18.2c-3.4-3.2-9.9-7.1-20.8-7.1H83v82.1h18.3V61.9L124.4,95.5z M106.1,51.1h-4.7
                    V27.5h5c3.3,0,7.9,0.5,10.8,2.7c2.6,2,4,5.1,4,8.8c0,4.4-2,7.2-3.2,8.4C114.6,50.6,109.8,51.1,106.1,51.1z M102.2,50.2h3.9
                    c3.5,0,8.1-0.4,11.1-3.4c1.1-1.1,3-3.6,3-7.8c0-3.5-1.2-6.3-3.7-8.1c-2.1-1.6-5.8-2.5-10.3-2.5h-4
                    C102.2,28.4,102.2,50.2,102.2,50.2z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M215.6,96.4h-47.8V12.5h47.8v17.1h-27.7v15.2h26.4v17.1h-26.4v17.6h27.8v17H215.6z M168.7,95.5h46.1V80.2
                    H187V60.9h26.4V45.6H187V28.7h27.8V13.4h-46.1V95.5z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M302.7,96.4h-68.2l39.8-66.8h-33V12.5h65.9l-39.7,66.8h35.3V96.4z M236,95.5h65.9V80.2H266l39.7-66.8h-63.6
                    v15.4h33.6L236,95.5z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M390,96.4h-68.2l39.8-66.8h-33V12.5h65.9l-39.7,66.8H390V96.4z M323.3,95.5h65.9V80.2h-35.9L393,13.5h-63.6
                    v15.4h33.6L323.3,95.5z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M460.2,96.4h-20v-39l-30.1-44.9h23.6l16.5,25.4l16.5-25.4h23.6l-30.1,44.9V96.4z M441.1,95.5h18.3V57.1
                    l29.4-43.7h-21.6l-16.9,26.1l-17-26.1h-21.6l29.4,43.7V95.5z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M540.9,96.4h-31.6V12.5H535c3.6,0,14.5,0,21.4,6.5c5.1,4.8,6.1,11.3,6.1,16c0,4.2-0.9,7.7-2.8,10.8
                    c-1.7,2.9-4,4.6-6,5.7c3.9,0.9,7.9,2.9,10.4,5.5c2.5,2.5,5.5,7.2,5.5,15.2c0,7-2.2,12.7-6.6,17.1C558,94,550.8,96.4,540.9,96.4z
                     M510,95.5h30.8c9.7,0,16.8-2.3,21.6-7c4.2-4.2,6.4-9.8,6.4-16.5c0-7.7-2.8-12.1-5.3-14.5c-2.7-2.7-7-4.8-11.2-5.5l-1.4-0.2
                    l1.3-0.6c2-0.9,4.7-2.6,6.8-6c1.8-2.9,2.6-6.3,2.6-10.3c0-4.4-1-10.8-5.9-15.4c-6.6-6.3-17.4-6.3-20.8-6.3h-25V95.5z
                     M533.2,81.5h-5.1v-21h5.7c3.9,0,10.5,0,13.9,3.2c0.8,0.7,2.7,2.9,2.7,7.1c0,3-1,5.6-2.8,7.3C543.9,81.5,537.4,81.5,533.2,81.5z
                     M528.9,80.6h4.1c4.1,0,10.4,0,13.8-3.2c1.7-1.6,2.6-3.8,2.6-6.7c0-3.8-1.9-5.9-2.4-6.4c-3.2-3-9.6-3-13.4-3h-4.7L528.9,80.6
                    L528.9,80.6z M531.7,47.1h-3.5V27.5h3.4c3.4,0,7.4,0,10.2,2.2c1,0.8,3.4,3,3.4,7.3c0,3.2-1.3,6.1-3.5,7.7
                    C538.6,46.8,534.1,47.1,531.7,47.1z M528.9,46.3h2.7c1.9,0,6.7-0.2,9.5-2.3c2-1.4,3.2-4,3.2-7c0-3.9-2.1-6-3-6.7
                    c-2.6-2-6.3-2-9.7-2h-2.5v18H528.9z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M634.4,98.2c-17.3,0-27.9-7.7-32.6-12.3c-8.3-7.8-13-19.2-13-31.1c0-11.4,5.1-23.9,12.9-31.8
                    c4.6-4.6,15-12.3,32.7-12.3c13.1,0,24,4.1,32.4,12.2c8.4,8.2,13,19.4,13,31.6c0,12-4.6,23.2-13,31.4
                    C658.4,94.1,647.4,98.2,634.4,98.2z M634.4,11.5c-16.6,0-26.7,6.6-32.1,12c-7.7,7.7-12.7,19.9-12.7,31.2
                    c0,11.8,4.6,22.9,12.8,30.5c4.7,4.5,15.2,12.1,32,12.1c12.8,0,23.5-4,31.8-12s12.8-19,12.8-30.8c0-12-4.5-23-12.8-31l0,0
                    C658,15.6,647.3,11.5,634.4,11.5z M634.1,80.5c-7.4,0-13.1-2.2-18.1-7c-5.2-5.1-7.7-11.3-7.7-19c0-10.3,4.6-16.4,7.5-19.1
                    c4.6-4.6,11.2-7.2,18.5-7.2c7,0,13.9,2.7,18.6,7.2c4.6,4.6,7.4,11.6,7.4,19c0,9.7-4,15.7-7.4,18.9
                    C648.2,78.1,641.7,80.5,634.1,80.5z M634.2,29.2c-7.1,0-13.3,2.4-17.9,7l0,0c-2.7,2.6-7.2,8.5-7.2,18.5c0,7.5,2.4,13.4,7.5,18.4
                    c4.8,4.5,10.4,6.8,17.5,6.8c7.3,0,13.5-2.4,18.1-7c3.2-3.1,7.1-8.8,7.1-18.2c0-10.2-5-16.3-7.1-18.4
                    C647.8,31.8,641,29.2,634.2,29.2z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path class="st1" d="M775.4,96.4h-24L733.1,68l-18.2,28.4h-24L721.7,52l-26.1-39.4h24l13.4,23.2l13.4-23.2h24L744.5,52
                    L775.4,96.4z M751.7,95.5h21.9l-30.2-43.6l25.5-38.5H747l-13.9,24l-13.8-24h-22l25.5,38.5l-0.2,0.2l-30,43.3h21.9L733,66.3
                    L751.7,95.5z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st2" d="M341.6,130.7c-1.3,1.1-3.1,1.8-5,1.8c-4.2,0-7.6-3-7.6-7.7c0-4.6,3.4-7.6,7.6-7.6c1.9,0,3.6,0.7,5,1.7
            l-0.9,1.1c-1.1-0.8-2.5-1.4-4.1-1.4c-3.4,0-6.2,2.4-6.2,6.2c0,3.8,2.8,6.3,6.2,6.3c1.5,0,2.9-0.5,4.1-1.4L341.6,130.7z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M345.5,132.1v-14.6h1.4v3.8c0.7-2.4,2.3-4.1,4.8-4.1c0.7,0,1.6,0.2,2.2,0.4l-0.2,1.4
            c-0.7-0.3-1.4-0.3-1.9-0.3c-3.8,0-4.8,4.3-4.8,7.8v5.6L345.5,132.1L345.5,132.1z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M370.1,125.4h-13c0.2,3.4,2.8,5.6,5.9,5.6c2.2,0,4.1-1.1,5.1-2.8l1.3,0.5c-1.3,2.3-3.7,3.7-6.4,3.7
            c-4.1,0-7.3-3-7.3-7.7c0-4.6,3.3-7.6,7.3-7.6c4.2,0,7.2,3,7.2,7.6C370.1,125,370.1,125.2,370.1,125.4z M357,124.1h11.6
            c-0.3-3.4-2.6-5.5-5.7-5.5S357.3,120.7,357,124.1z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M387.2,129c-1.2,2.1-3.6,3.5-6.2,3.5c-4.2,0-7.5-3.3-7.5-7.6c0-4.4,3.4-7.6,7.5-7.6c2.6,0,5,1.3,6.2,3.4v-3.1
            h1.4v14.6h-1.4V129z M381,131c3.3,0,6.1-2.5,6.2-6c0-3.7-2.8-6.3-6.2-6.3c-3.4,0-6.1,2.6-6.1,6.2C374.9,128.4,377.6,131,381,131z"
            />
        <path class="st2" d="M399.7,118.8h-3.4v13.3h-1.4v-13.3h-2.7v-1.3h2.7v-5.9h1.4v5.9h3.4V118.8z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M403.9,111c0.7,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2s-0.5,1.2-1.2,1.2s-1.3-0.5-1.3-1.2C402.7,111.5,403.3,111,403.9,111z
             M403.3,117.5v14.6h1.4v-14.6C404.7,117.5,403.3,117.5,403.3,117.5z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M409.9,117.5h1.4v2.9c0.8-2.3,3.2-3.2,5.2-3.2c3.5,0,5.8,2.4,5.8,6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9
            s-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2h-1.4V117.5z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M428.9,135.3c1.2,1.8,3,2.7,4.9,2.7c3.8,0,6.4-1.8,6.4-8v-1.1c-1.1,2.2-3.6,3.5-6.2,3.5
            c-4.2,0-7.5-3.2-7.5-7.6c0-4.4,3.4-7.6,7.5-7.6c2.6,0,5,1.3,6.2,3.5v-3.2h1.4v12.4c0,7.3-3.2,9.5-7.8,9.5c-2.3,0-4.6-1-6.1-3.3
            L428.9,135.3z M434,131c3.3,0,6.2-2.5,6.2-6.2c0-3.6-2.8-6.2-6.2-6.2c-3.4,0-6.1,2.7-6.1,6.2C427.9,128.4,430.6,131,434,131z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M467.9,132.1v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2h-1.4v-14.6h1.4v2.9c0.8-2.3,3.3-3.2,5.2-3.2
            c2.6,0,4.6,1.3,5.4,3.8c1-3.1,3.8-3.8,5.6-3.8c3.4,0,5.8,2.4,5.8,6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2
            L467.9,132.1L467.9,132.1z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M484.6,124.8c0-4.6,3.4-7.6,7.6-7.6s7.6,2.9,7.6,7.6c0,4.7-3.5,7.7-7.6,7.7
            C488,132.4,484.6,129.4,484.6,124.8z M498.4,124.8c0-3.8-2.8-6.2-6.2-6.2c-3.4,0-6.2,2.4-6.2,6.2s2.8,6.3,6.2,6.3
            C495.6,131,498.4,128.6,498.4,124.8z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M515.2,132.1v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2h-1.4v-14.6h1.4v2.9c0.8-2.3,3.3-3.2,5.2-3.2
            c2.6,0,4.6,1.3,5.4,3.8c1-3.1,3.8-3.8,5.6-3.8c3.4,0,5.8,2.4,5.8,6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9c-2.6,0-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3
            v8.2L515.2,132.1L515.2,132.1z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M546.4,125.4h-13c0.2,3.4,2.8,5.6,5.9,5.6c2.2,0,4.1-1.1,5.1-2.8l1.3,0.5c-1.3,2.3-3.7,3.7-6.4,3.7
            c-4.1,0-7.3-3-7.3-7.7c0-4.6,3.3-7.6,7.3-7.6c4.2,0,7.2,3,7.2,7.6C546.4,125,546.4,125.2,546.4,125.4z M533.3,124.1H545
            c-0.3-3.4-2.6-5.5-5.7-5.5C536.1,118.6,533.6,120.7,533.3,124.1z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M550.6,117.5h1.4v2.9c0.8-2.3,3.2-3.2,5.2-3.2c3.5,0,5.8,2.4,5.8,6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9
            c-2.6,0-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2h-1.4L550.6,117.5L550.6,117.5z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M573.5,118.8h-3.4v13.3h-1.4v-13.3H566v-1.3h2.7v-5.9h1.4v5.9h3.4L573.5,118.8L573.5,118.8z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M585.7,120.9h-1.4c-0.2-1.4-1.5-2.3-3.1-2.3c-1.7,0-3,0.9-3.2,2.1c-0.3,2.1,1.3,2.7,2.5,3l2.1,0.5
            c2.7,0.7,3.6,2.2,3.6,4c0,2.5-2.1,4.2-5.1,4.2c-2.4,0-4.8-1.4-5.1-4h1.3c0.4,1.2,1.3,2.7,3.9,2.7c2.2,0,3.6-1.1,3.6-2.8
            c0-1.2-0.7-2.2-2.5-2.7l-2.1-0.5c-1.8-0.4-3.9-1.3-3.6-4.6c0.3-2,2.3-3.3,4.6-3.3C583.6,117.2,585.5,118.5,585.7,120.9z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M599.4,124.8c0-4.6,3.4-7.6,7.6-7.6c4.2,0,7.6,2.9,7.6,7.6c0,4.7-3.5,7.7-7.6,7.7
            C602.8,132.4,599.4,129.4,599.4,124.8z M613.2,124.8c0-3.8-2.8-6.2-6.2-6.2s-6.2,2.4-6.2,6.2s2.8,6.3,6.2,6.3
            C610.4,131,613.2,128.6,613.2,124.8z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M616.7,118.8v-1.3h2.9v-2.1c0-3.5,1.2-6.2,5-6.2h1.3v1.4h-1.3c-2.9,0-3.6,2.3-3.6,4.8v2.1h3.9v1.3H621v13.3
            h-1.4v-13.3C619.6,118.9,616.7,118.9,616.7,118.8z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M638.3,109.2h1.4v11.2c0.8-2.3,3.2-3.2,5.2-3.2c3.4,0,5.8,2.4,5.8,6.3v8.6c-0.2,0-1.2,0-1.4,0v-8.6
            c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9c-2.6,0-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2h-1.4L638.3,109.2L638.3,109.2z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M668.6,129c-1.2,2.1-3.6,3.5-6.2,3.5c-4.2,0-7.5-3.3-7.5-7.6c0-4.4,3.4-7.6,7.5-7.6c2.6,0,5,1.3,6.2,3.4v-3.1
            h1.4v14.6h-1.4V129z M662.4,131c3.3,0,6.1-2.5,6.2-6c0-3.7-2.8-6.3-6.2-6.3s-6.1,2.6-6.1,6.2C656.3,128.4,659,131,662.4,131z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M676.7,120.7c1.2-2.1,3.6-3.5,6.2-3.5c4.2,0,7.5,3.3,7.5,7.7s-3.4,7.6-7.5,7.6c-2.6,0-5-1.3-6.2-3.4v10.2
            h-1.4v-21.7h1.4V120.7z M682.9,118.6c-3.3,0-6.1,2.5-6.2,6.1c0,3.7,2.8,6.3,6.2,6.3s6.1-2.6,6.1-6.1
            C689,121.4,686.3,118.6,682.9,118.6z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M696.3,120.7c1.2-2.1,3.6-3.5,6.2-3.5c4.2,0,7.5,3.3,7.5,7.7s-3.4,7.6-7.5,7.6c-2.6,0-5-1.3-6.2-3.4v10.2
            h-1.4v-21.7h1.4V120.7z M702.4,118.6c-3.3,0-6.1,2.5-6.2,6.1c0,3.7,2.8,6.3,6.2,6.3s6.1-2.6,6.1-6.1
            C708.5,121.4,705.8,118.6,702.4,118.6z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M715,111c0.7,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2s-0.5,1.2-1.2,1.2s-1.3-0.5-1.3-1.2C713.8,111.5,714.3,111,715,111z
             M714.3,117.5v14.6h1.4v-14.6C715.7,117.5,714.3,117.5,714.3,117.5z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M721,117.5h1.4v2.9c0.8-2.3,3.2-3.2,5.2-3.2c3.5,0,5.8,2.4,5.8,6.3v8.6H732v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9
            c-2.6,0-5.1,1.4-5.2,5.3v8.2H721V117.5z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M752.1,125.4h-13c0.2,3.4,2.8,5.6,5.9,5.6c2.2,0,4.1-1.1,5.1-2.8l1.3,0.5c-1.3,2.3-3.7,3.7-6.4,3.7
            c-4.1,0-7.3-3-7.3-7.7c0-4.6,3.3-7.6,7.3-7.6c4.2,0,7.2,3,7.2,7.6C752.1,125,752.1,125.2,752.1,125.4z M739.1,124.1h11.6
            c-0.3-3.4-2.6-5.5-5.7-5.5C741.8,118.6,739.3,120.7,739.1,124.1z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M764.9,120.9h-1.4c-0.2-1.4-1.5-2.3-3.1-2.3c-1.7,0-3,0.9-3.2,2.1c-0.3,2.1,1.3,2.7,2.5,3l2.1,0.5
            c2.7,0.7,3.6,2.2,3.6,4c0,2.5-2.1,4.2-5.1,4.2c-2.4,0-4.8-1.4-5.1-4h1.3c0.4,1.2,1.3,2.7,3.9,2.7c2.2,0,3.6-1.1,3.6-2.8
            c0-1.2-0.7-2.2-2.5-2.7l-2.1-0.5c-1.8-0.4-3.9-1.3-3.6-4.6c0.3-2,2.3-3.3,4.6-3.3C762.8,117.2,764.6,118.5,764.9,120.9z"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M778.5,120.9h-1.4c-0.2-1.4-1.5-2.3-3.1-2.3c-1.7,0-3,0.9-3.2,2.1c-0.3,2.1,1.3,2.7,2.5,3l2.1,0.5
            c2.7,0.7,3.6,2.2,3.6,4c0,2.5-2.1,4.2-5.1,4.2c-2.4,0-4.8-1.4-5.1-4h1.3c0.4,1.2,1.3,2.7,3.9,2.7c2.2,0,3.6-1.1,3.6-2.8
            c0-1.2-0.7-2.2-2.5-2.7l-2.1-0.5c-1.8-0.4-3.9-1.3-3.6-4.6c0.3-2,2.3-3.3,4.6-3.3C776.3,117.2,778.2,118.5,778.5,120.9z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbdrzE

Comment: What do you mean by flattened SVG? a .png? Also please add the code to your question. Just click the edit below the tags

Comment: I've tried to add code to the question and it won't accept the codepen. I mean an SVG whereby each element (each letter in this instance) isn't standalone, they're grouped together to one flattened vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 different colors, so you're going to get, at best, 3 `paths`. Illustrator exports `<style>` tags with CSS, and that's not necessary here, so I inlined your `fill` declarations as attrs on the `path`s and ditched some extraneous bits (e.g. the top level ID, class names, useless groups), ran through SVGO (using [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)) and this is the result:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 780 150">
  <path fill="#edc0f9" d="M35.2 17.3A31 31 0 0 1 57 24.2a25.6 25.6 0 0 1 8.1 20.2c0 10.4-3.9 16.3-7.1 19.5-6.6 6.8-15.3 7.4-21.1 7.4H25v29.1H5.8V17.3h29.4zM25 55.5h6.9c2.6 0 7.2-.1 10.3-3.1 1.7-1.7 3.1-4.6 3.1-8.2a11 11 0 0 0-3.1-8.1c-2.8-2.7-7-3.1-10.7-3.1H25v22.5zm91.2-38.2c10.6 0 17.2 3.4 21.1 7.2 3.4 3.3 7.2 9.3 7.2 18.5 0 5.3-1.1 11.7-6.5 16.9-2.8 2.7-7 5.3-11.6 6.4l25.5 33.9h-23.4l-22.1-32.6v32.7H87.1v-83h29.1zM106.3 55h4.3c3.4 0 8.2-.4 11.4-3.6a11 11 0 0 0 3.1-8.1c0-4.7-2.2-7.2-3.8-8.5-3.1-2.3-8.1-2.6-10.6-2.6h-4.4V55zm113.3-21.5H192v16.1h26.4v16.2H192v18.4h27.8v16.2h-47v-83h46.9v16.1zm51.6 50.6h35.6v16.2h-67.1l39.8-66.7h-33.3V17.4h64.7l-39.7 66.7zm87.3 0H394v16.2h-67l39.8-66.8h-33.3V17.3h64.7l-39.7 66.8zm86.7-22.5l-29.7-44.3h22.6l16.7 25.8 16.7-25.8h22.6l-29.7 44.3v38.7h-19.2V61.6zm94.2-44.3c4.4 0 14.7.2 21.1 6.4 5.4 5.1 6 12 6 15.7 0 3.2-.5 7-2.7 10.6-2.1 3.4-5 5.3-7 6.1 3.9.6 8.5 2.6 11.4 5.6 2.7 2.7 5.4 7.5 5.4 14.9 0 8.4-3.2 13.5-6.5 16.8-6.9 6.6-16.8 7.1-21.9 7.1H514v-83h25.4zM533 50.9h3.1c2.6 0 7-.4 9.7-2.3 1.7-1.2 3.3-3.7 3.3-7.4s-1.7-5.9-3.2-7c-2.7-2.1-6.5-2.1-10-2.1h-3v18.8h.1zm0 34.4h4.6c4.8 0 10.7-.1 14.1-3.3a9.2 9.2 0 0 0 2.7-7c0-3.3-1.4-5.6-2.6-6.7-3.3-3.1-9.8-3.1-13.6-3.1H533v20.1zm138-57.8a42.8 42.8 0 0 1 12.9 31.3 42.6 42.6 0 0 1-45 43.3 45.5 45.5 0 0 1-32.3-12.2 42.3 42.3 0 0 1-12.9-30.8c0-11.9 5.4-24 12.8-31.5 5.6-5.6 16-12.2 32.4-12.2 12.9 0 23.7 4 32.1 12.1zm-50.4 12.6a25.4 25.4 0 0 0-7.4 18.8 25 25 0 0 0 7.6 18.7 24.5 24.5 0 0 0 17.8 6.9 25 25 0 0 0 18.4-7.1 25 25 0 0 0 7.2-18.5c0-8.6-3.4-15-7.2-18.7a27 27 0 0 0-18.3-7.1c-7.2 0-13.7 2.6-18.1 7zm106.1 16.1l-25.8-38.9h23l13.6 23.6 13.6-23.6h23l-25.8 38.9 30.5 44.1h-23l-18.4-28.7-18.4 28.7h-23l30.7-44.1z"/>
  <path fill="#333" d="M21 96.4H1V12.5h29.7c6.7 0 15.2.8 22 7 5.6 4.8 8.2 11.5 8.2 20.5 0 8.2-2.4 14.9-7.2 19.8-6.5 6.7-14.9 7.5-21.4 7.5H21v29.1zm-19.2-.9h18.4V66.4h12.1c6.4 0 14.5-.8 20.8-7.2 4.6-4.8 7-11.3 7-19.2 0-8.7-2.6-15.2-8-19.8a31 31 0 0 0-21.4-6.9H1.8v82.2zm25.7-43.8h-7.3V28.2h6.9c3.7 0 8 .4 11 3.2 2 1.9 3.2 5 3.2 8.4 0 3.3-1.2 6.5-3.2 8.5-3.5 3.4-8.5 3.4-10.6 3.4zm-6.5-1h6.4c2 0 6.9 0 10-3 1.9-1.9 2.9-4.7 2.9-7.9s-1.1-6-2.9-7.8c-2.7-2.6-6.8-3-10.4-3h-6.1l.1 21.7zm127.4 45.7H124l-21.7-31.7v31.7H82.1V12.5h29.5c11.2 0 17.9 3.9 21.4 7.4 2.7 2.6 7.4 8.6 7.4 18.9 0 7.3-2.1 12.9-6.6 17.3-3 2.9-7.1 5.2-11.1 6.3l25.7 34zm-24-.9h22.3l-25.4-33.8.6-.2c4.1-1 8.3-3.2 11.4-6.3 4.2-4.1 6.4-9.6 6.4-16.6 0-9.9-4.4-15.7-7.1-18.2a29.4 29.4 0 0 0-20.8-7.1H83v82.1h18.3V61.9l23.1 33.6zm-18.3-44.4h-4.7V27.5h5c3.3 0 7.9.5 10.8 2.7 2.6 2 4 5.1 4 8.8 0 4.4-2 7.2-3.2 8.4-3.4 3.2-8.2 3.7-11.9 3.7zm-3.9-.9h3.9c3.5 0 8.1-.4 11.1-3.4 1.1-1.1 3-3.6 3-7.8 0-3.5-1.2-6.3-3.7-8.1a17.7 17.7 0 0 0-10.3-2.5h-4v21.8zm113.4 46.2h-47.8V12.5h47.8v17.1h-27.7v15.2h26.4v17.1h-26.4v17.6h27.8v17h-.1zm-46.9-.9h46.1V80.2H187V60.9h26.4V45.6H187V28.7h27.8V13.4h-46.1v82.1zm134 .9h-68.2l39.8-66.8h-33V12.5h65.9l-39.7 66.8h35.3v17.1zm-66.7-.9h65.9V80.2H266l39.7-66.8h-63.6v15.4h33.6L236 95.5zm154 .9h-68.2l39.8-66.8h-33V12.5h65.9l-39.7 66.8H390v17.1zm-66.7-.9h65.9V80.2h-35.9L393 13.5h-63.6v15.4H363l-39.7 66.6zm136.9.9h-20v-39l-30.1-44.9h23.6l16.5 25.4 16.5-25.4h23.6l-30.1 44.9v39zm-19.1-.9h18.3V57.1l29.4-43.7h-21.6l-16.9 26.1-17-26.1h-21.6l29.4 43.7v38.4zm99.8.9h-31.6V12.5H535c3.6 0 14.5 0 21.4 6.5a21.4 21.4 0 0 1 6.1 16 20 20 0 0 1-2.8 10.8c-1.7 2.9-4 4.6-6 5.7 3.9.9 7.9 2.9 10.4 5.5 2.5 2.5 5.5 7.2 5.5 15.2 0 7-2.2 12.7-6.6 17.1-5 4.7-12.2 7.1-22.1 7.1zm-30.9-.9h30.8c9.7 0 16.8-2.3 21.6-7 4.2-4.2 6.4-9.8 6.4-16.5 0-7.7-2.8-12.1-5.3-14.5-2.7-2.7-7-4.8-11.2-5.5l-1.4-.2 1.3-.6c2-.9 4.7-2.6 6.8-6a19 19 0 0 0 2.6-10.3c0-4.4-1-10.8-5.9-15.4-6.6-6.3-17.4-6.3-20.8-6.3h-25v82.3zm23.2-14h-5.1v-21h5.7c3.9 0 10.5 0 13.9 3.2.8.7 2.7 2.9 2.7 7.1 0 3-1 5.6-2.8 7.3-3.7 3.4-10.2 3.4-14.4 3.4zm-4.3-.9h4.1c4.1 0 10.4 0 13.8-3.2a8.7 8.7 0 0 0 2.6-6.7 9 9 0 0 0-2.4-6.4c-3.2-3-9.6-3-13.4-3h-4.7v19.3zm2.8-33.5h-3.5V27.5h3.4c3.4 0 7.4 0 10.2 2.2a9 9 0 0 1 3.4 7.3c0 3.2-1.3 6.1-3.5 7.7a19 19 0 0 1-10 2.4zm-2.8-.8h2.7c1.9 0 6.7-.2 9.5-2.3 2-1.4 3.2-4 3.2-7 0-3.9-2.1-6-3-6.7-2.6-2-6.3-2-9.7-2h-2.5v18h-.2zm105.5 51.9a45.8 45.8 0 0 1-32.6-12.3 42.7 42.7 0 0 1-13-31.1c0-11.4 5.1-23.9 12.9-31.8a45 45 0 0 1 32.7-12.3 45 45 0 0 1 32.4 12.2c8.4 8.2 13 19.4 13 31.6 0 12-4.6 23.2-13 31.4s-19.4 12.3-32.4 12.3zm0-86.7a43.9 43.9 0 0 0-32.1 12 46.1 46.1 0 0 0-12.7 31.2c0 11.8 4.6 22.9 12.8 30.5a45.6 45.6 0 0 0 32 12.1A42.4 42.4 0 0 0 679 54.5c0-12-4.5-23-12.8-31a44.2 44.2 0 0 0-31.8-12zm-.3 69a25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.8-26c0-10.3 4.6-16.4 7.5-19.1a26 26 0 0 1 18.5-7.2c7 0 13.9 2.7 18.6 7.2a27.1 27.1 0 0 1 7.4 19c0 9.7-4 15.7-7.4 18.9a25.5 25.5 0 0 1-18.8 7.2zm.1-51.3c-7.1 0-13.3 2.4-17.9 7a25 25 0 0 0-7.2 18.5 24.3 24.3 0 0 0 25 25.2c7.3 0 13.5-2.4 18.1-7 3.2-3.1 7.1-8.8 7.1-18.2 0-10.2-5-16.3-7.1-18.4a25.6 25.6 0 0 0-18-7.1zm141.2 67.2h-24L733.1 68l-18.2 28.4h-24L721.7 52l-26.1-39.4h24L733 35.8l13.4-23.2h24L744.5 52l30.9 44.4zm-23.7-.9h21.9l-30.2-43.6 25.5-38.5H747l-13.9 24-13.8-24h-22l25.5 38.5-.2.2-30 43.3h21.9L733 66.3l18.7 29.2z"/>
  <path fill="#d892ec" d="M341.6 130.7a7.8 7.8 0 0 1-5 1.8c-4.2 0-7.6-3-7.6-7.7 0-4.6 3.4-7.6 7.6-7.6 1.9 0 3.6.7 5 1.7l-.9 1.1a7 7 0 0 0-4.1-1.4 6 6 0 0 0-6.2 6.2 6 6 0 0 0 6.2 6.3c1.5 0 2.9-.5 4.1-1.4l.9 1zm3.9 1.4v-14.6h1.4v3.8c.7-2.4 2.3-4.1 4.8-4.1.7 0 1.6.2 2.2.4l-.2 1.4c-.7-.3-1.4-.3-1.9-.3-3.8 0-4.8 4.3-4.8 7.8v5.6h-1.5zm24.6-6.7h-13a5.8 5.8 0 0 0 5.9 5.6c2.2 0 4.1-1.1 5.1-2.8l1.3.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1-6.4 3.7c-4.1 0-7.3-3-7.3-7.7 0-4.6 3.3-7.6 7.3-7.6 4.2 0 7.2 3 7.2 7.6l-.1.7zm-13.1-1.3h11.6c-.3-3.4-2.6-5.5-5.7-5.5s-5.6 2.1-5.9 5.5zm30.2 4.9a7.2 7.2 0 0 1-6.2 3.5 7.5 7.5 0 0 1-7.5-7.6c0-4.4 3.4-7.6 7.5-7.6 2.6 0 5 1.3 6.2 3.4v-3.1h1.4v14.6h-1.4V129zm-6.2 2c3.3 0 6.1-2.5 6.2-6 0-3.7-2.8-6.3-6.2-6.3a6 6 0 0 0-6.1 6.2 6 6 0 0 0 6.1 6.1zm18.7-12.2h-3.4v13.3h-1.4v-13.3h-2.7v-1.3h2.7v-5.9h1.4v5.9h3.4v1.3zm4.2-7.8c.7 0 1.2.5 1.2 1.2s-.5 1.2-1.2 1.2-1.3-.5-1.3-1.2c.1-.7.7-1.2 1.3-1.2zm-.6 6.5v14.6h1.4v-14.6h-1.4zm6.6 0h1.4v2.9c.8-2.3 3.2-3.2 5.2-3.2 3.5 0 5.8 2.4 5.8 6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4v-14.6zm19 17.8c1.2 1.8 3 2.7 4.9 2.7 3.8 0 6.4-1.8 6.4-8v-1.1a6.9 6.9 0 0 1-6.2 3.5 7.4 7.4 0 0 1-7.5-7.6c0-4.4 3.4-7.6 7.5-7.6a7 7 0 0 1 6.2 3.5v-3.2h1.4v12.4c0 7.3-3.2 9.5-7.8 9.5-2.3 0-4.6-1-6.1-3.3l1.2-.8zm5.1-4.3c3.3 0 6.2-2.5 6.2-6.2 0-3.6-2.8-6.2-6.2-6.2a6 6 0 0 0-6.1 6.2 6 6 0 0 0 6.1 6.2zm33.9 1.1v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4v-14.6h1.4v2.9c.8-2.3 3.3-3.2 5.2-3.2 2.6 0 4.6 1.3 5.4 3.8 1-3.1 3.8-3.8 5.6-3.8 3.4 0 5.8 2.4 5.8 6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4zm16.7-7.3c0-4.6 3.4-7.6 7.6-7.6s7.6 2.9 7.6 7.6c0 4.7-3.5 7.7-7.6 7.7a7.5 7.5 0 0 1-7.6-7.7zm13.8 0a6 6 0 0 0-6.2-6.2c-3.4 0-6.2 2.4-6.2 6.2s2.8 6.3 6.2 6.3a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 6.2-6.3zm16.8 7.3v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9s-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4v-14.6h1.4v2.9c.8-2.3 3.3-3.2 5.2-3.2 2.6 0 4.6 1.3 5.4 3.8 1-3.1 3.8-3.8 5.6-3.8 3.4 0 5.8 2.4 5.8 6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9-2.6 0-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4zm31.2-6.7h-13a5.8 5.8 0 0 0 5.9 5.6c2.2 0 4.1-1.1 5.1-2.8l1.3.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1-6.4 3.7c-4.1 0-7.3-3-7.3-7.7 0-4.6 3.3-7.6 7.3-7.6 4.2 0 7.2 3 7.2 7.6l-.1.7zm-13.1-1.3H545c-.3-3.4-2.6-5.5-5.7-5.5a5.8 5.8 0 0 0-6 5.5zm17.3-6.6h1.4v2.9c.8-2.3 3.2-3.2 5.2-3.2 3.5 0 5.8 2.4 5.8 6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9-2.6 0-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4v-14.6zm22.9 1.3h-3.4v13.3h-1.4v-13.3H566v-1.3h2.7v-5.9h1.4v5.9h3.4v1.3zm12.2 2.1h-1.4c-.2-1.4-1.5-2.3-3.1-2.3-1.7 0-3 .9-3.2 2.1-.3 2.1 1.3 2.7 2.5 3l2.1.5c2.7.7 3.6 2.2 3.6 4 0 2.5-2.1 4.2-5.1 4.2-2.4 0-4.8-1.4-5.1-4h1.3c.4 1.2 1.3 2.7 3.9 2.7 2.2 0 3.6-1.1 3.6-2.8 0-1.2-.7-2.2-2.5-2.7l-2.1-.5c-1.8-.4-3.9-1.3-3.6-4.6.3-2 2.3-3.3 4.6-3.3 2.4 0 4.3 1.3 4.5 3.7zm13.7 3.9c0-4.6 3.4-7.6 7.6-7.6 4.2 0 7.6 2.9 7.6 7.6 0 4.7-3.5 7.7-7.6 7.7a7.5 7.5 0 0 1-7.6-7.7zm13.8 0c0-3.8-2.8-6.2-6.2-6.2s-6.2 2.4-6.2 6.2 2.8 6.3 6.2 6.3a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 6.2-6.3zm3.5-6v-1.3h2.9v-2.1c0-3.5 1.2-6.2 5-6.2h1.3v1.4h-1.3c-2.9 0-3.6 2.3-3.6 4.8v2.1h3.9v1.3H621v13.3h-1.4v-13.3h-2.9zm21.6-9.6h1.4v11.2c.8-2.3 3.2-3.2 5.2-3.2 3.4 0 5.8 2.4 5.8 6.3v8.6h-1.4v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9-2.6 0-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2h-1.4v-22.9zm30.3 19.8a7.2 7.2 0 0 1-6.2 3.5 7.5 7.5 0 0 1-7.5-7.6c0-4.4 3.4-7.6 7.5-7.6 2.6 0 5 1.3 6.2 3.4v-3.1h1.4v14.6h-1.4V129zm-6.2 2c3.3 0 6.1-2.5 6.2-6 0-3.7-2.8-6.3-6.2-6.3s-6.1 2.6-6.1 6.2a6 6 0 0 0 6.1 6.1zm14.3-10.3a7.2 7.2 0 0 1 6.2-3.5c4.2 0 7.5 3.3 7.5 7.7s-3.4 7.6-7.5 7.6c-2.6 0-5-1.3-6.2-3.4v10.2h-1.4v-21.7h1.4v3.1zm6.2-2.1a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-6.2 6.1c0 3.7 2.8 6.3 6.2 6.3s6.1-2.6 6.1-6.1c0-3.5-2.7-6.3-6.1-6.3zm13.4 2.1a7.2 7.2 0 0 1 6.2-3.5c4.2 0 7.5 3.3 7.5 7.7s-3.4 7.6-7.5 7.6c-2.6 0-5-1.3-6.2-3.4v10.2h-1.4v-21.7h1.4v3.1zm6.1-2.1a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-6.2 6.1c0 3.7 2.8 6.3 6.2 6.3s6.1-2.6 6.1-6.1c0-3.5-2.7-6.3-6.1-6.3zM715 111c.7 0 1.2.5 1.2 1.2s-.5 1.2-1.2 1.2-1.3-.5-1.3-1.2c.1-.7.6-1.2 1.3-1.2zm-.7 6.5v14.6h1.4v-14.6h-1.4zm6.7 0h1.4v2.9c.8-2.3 3.2-3.2 5.2-3.2 3.5 0 5.8 2.4 5.8 6.3v8.6H732v-8.6c0-3.1-1.8-4.9-4.4-4.9-2.6 0-5.1 1.4-5.2 5.3v8.2H721v-14.6zm31.1 7.9h-13a5.8 5.8 0 0 0 5.9 5.6c2.2 0 4.1-1.1 5.1-2.8l1.3.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1-6.4 3.7c-4.1 0-7.3-3-7.3-7.7 0-4.6 3.3-7.6 7.3-7.6 4.2 0 7.2 3 7.2 7.6l-.1.7zm-13-1.3h11.6c-.3-3.4-2.6-5.5-5.7-5.5a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-5.9 5.5zm25.8-3.2h-1.4c-.2-1.4-1.5-2.3-3.1-2.3-1.7 0-3 .9-3.2 2.1-.3 2.1 1.3 2.7 2.5 3l2.1.5c2.7.7 3.6 2.2 3.6 4 0 2.5-2.1 4.2-5.1 4.2-2.4 0-4.8-1.4-5.1-4h1.3c.4 1.2 1.3 2.7 3.9 2.7 2.2 0 3.6-1.1 3.6-2.8 0-1.2-.7-2.2-2.5-2.7l-2.1-.5c-1.8-.4-3.9-1.3-3.6-4.6.3-2 2.3-3.3 4.6-3.3 2.4 0 4.2 1.3 4.5 3.7zm13.6 0h-1.4c-.2-1.4-1.5-2.3-3.1-2.3-1.7 0-3 .9-3.2 2.1-.3 2.1 1.3 2.7 2.5 3l2.1.5c2.7.7 3.6 2.2 3.6 4 0 2.5-2.1 4.2-5.1 4.2-2.4 0-4.8-1.4-5.1-4h1.3c.4 1.2 1.3 2.7 3.9 2.7 2.2 0 3.6-1.1 3.6-2.8 0-1.2-.7-2.2-2.5-2.7l-2.1-.5c-1.8-.4-3.9-1.3-3.6-4.6.3-2 2.3-3.3 4.6-3.3s4.2 1.3 4.5 3.7z"/>
</svg>
```

It's <4kb when gzipped, which is great.

Comment: This is fantastic - thank you so much. Really appreciate that